# Creating a vowel variable for multiple inputs in a loop

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to create a variable within a loop that will print "an" in a response if the first letter of that response is a vowel. Here's my script:

```
responses = {}

polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
    response = input("Which kind of sandwich do you want? ")

    if response[0] in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'):
        a_an = "an"
    else:
        a_an = "a"

    responses[name] = response

    repeat = input("Would you like to let another person order? (yes/no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_active = False

print("\n-- Order --")
for name, response in responses.items():
    print(name + " would like " + a_an + " " + response + " sandwich.")
```

Here's the output. When just one order is taken, the variable works, but when multiple orders are taken, the `a_an` variable remains the same.

```
Python ❯ python3 sandwich_orders.py                                                  ⏎

What is your name? Alex
Which kind of sandwich do you want? egg
Would you like to let another person order? (yes/no) no

-- Order --
Alex would like an egg sandwich.
Python ❯ python3 sandwich_orders.py

What is your name? Alex
Which kind of sandwich do you want? ham
Would you like to let another person order? (yes/no) no

-- Order --
Alex would like a ham sandwich.
Python ❯ python3 sandwich_orders.py

What is your name? Alex
Which kind of sandwich do you want? egg
Would you like to let another person order? (yes/no) yes

What is your name? Steve
Which kind of sandwich do you want? ham
Would you like to let another person order? (yes/no) no

-- Order --
Alex would like a egg sandwich.
Steve would like a ham sandwich.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to programming! You are almost there. Move the

> ```
> if response[0] in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'):
>     a_an = "an"
> else:
>     a_an = "a"
> ```

Inside the for loop before the print.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you overwrite your `a_an` variable each time you make an additional order. You need to save it instead for each order in a batch. One way to do it is to simply concatenate it within the while loop with the response,

```
responses[name] = a_an + ' ' + response
```

With this fix the rest of your program remains the same except:

```
for name, response in responses.items():
    print(name + " would like " + response + " sandwich.")
```

Comment: That's a great approach! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need another list to store the different values of `a_an` for the different responses. If not, it just takes the value of the last response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not saving the separator `(a, an)` for each iteration. My solution saves the value within the pre-existing dictionary for use later!

```
if response[0].lower() in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):#we can also convert to lowercase and check a modified list. Just to shorten, not necessary
        a_an = "an"
    else:
        a_an = "a"

    responses[name] = [a_an, response] #modify dict to contain [delimiter, response]

#... other code here

for name, response in responses.items():
    print(name + " would like " + response[0] + " " + response[1] + " sandwich.")
    #where response[0] is our delimiter and response[1] is our type
```

Comment: This method makes a lot more sense than the way I had it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I created a little procedure to fix your problem.

```
name = 'Alex'
#storing the sandwiches types
#new values: types.append('value')
types = ['ham','egg']

for i in range(0,len(types)):

    response = types[i]

    if response[0] in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'):
        a_an = "an"
    else:
        a_an = "a"

    print(name + " would like " + a_an + " " + response + " sandwich.")
```

It's important to keep your evaluation list inside the for loop.
Because of the len(types) it will evaluate the expression dinamically for all the elements in the list.